# Fetch results using JPA Criteria Builder where contains numeric fields only where attribute having alphanumeric values in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I wanted to know how to query with JPA CriteriaBuilder where the attribue `userCode` of type String represents a number.

I'm having :

```
Id    name    userCode
1     ABC     ABCD_123
2     XYZ     ABC_EFGH
3     TEST    7845
4     TEst2   85245
```

Now i just wanted to get result having `userCode` value only numeric.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly cast string to number with JPA2 Criteria API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394176/how-to-properly-cast-string-to-number-with-jpa2-criteria-api)

Comment: @perissf I don't think it's duplicate question. I'm not parsing string . My Requirement is different.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no function in JPA to do this (JPA relationship through a collection will show all related elements no matter how they were numeric or not). Anyway, you can approach either using a native query to make database to return them filter or using any feature of your JPA implementation like this:

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_regexp.htm

Which allow JPA to use regular expressions with retrieved rows.

Comment: Can't we use Criteria Builder for this rather JPQL ?

Comment: Of course but i usually prefer jpql than criteria builder because, if annotated as named queries, they are compiled before execution and it prevents fails on execution time but it's your decision how to implement it

Comment: I'm totally agree with you dear. But here is different scenario so i want it using Criteria Builder rather JPQL. And thanks for the link , it's beneficial

Answer (score 1):

You can call functions using `CriteriaBuilder.function(name, ret_type, args)`.

You haven't said what DBMS your are using, so I'm assuming you have some function available that you could call in SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE is_numeric(userCode);
```

You could represent that in Criteria API as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);
Path<String> userCode = root.get(User_.userCode);
Expression<Boolean> numeric = builder.function("is_numeric", Boolean.class, userCode);

query.select(root).where(numeric);
```

See [API Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...)) for `function(...)`.

---

**EDIT** possible function in MySQL (untested)

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_numeric(val VARCHAR(1024)) 
RETURNS TINYINT(1) DETERMINISTIC 
RETURN val REGEXP '^(-|\\+)?([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';
```

[(source)](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,599995,599995)

Comment: side note: the `function` method was introduced in JPA 2.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Eclipselink` then you can use [Regular expression](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions) `REGEXP`    function (evaluates if the `string` matches the regular expression as of 2.4) or its better to use native query this requirement. In native query you can use `REGEXP_LIKE` function for example to find non numeric characters:

```
SELECT *
  FROM <table>
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(<column>, '[^[:digit:]]');
```

Comment: Ummm.. thanks for the nice answer but dear i want the solution using JPA Criteria Builder rather JPQL.