# Cast Id column type of Long to Text so LIKE can be applied

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, casting

I am using CriteriaBuilder to create a Query that returns a List of MyOwnEntitiy. In my entity I have a @Id that is type of Long but I have the need to query the entity when id is like '%3%'. In plain sql I have several options:

```
select * from MyOwnTable where concat(id,id) like '%3'
select * from MyOwnTable where id::text like '%3'
select * from MyOwnTable where cast(id as text) like '%3'
```

but when using hibernate and criteriaBuilder I get stuck when trying to cast to text.

I tried to use @Formula annotation in myOwnEntity:

```
 @Formula("id::Text")
    private String idToText;
```

but still get the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%3%] did not
>   match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]

```
final CriteriaQuery<MyOwnEntitiy> criteriaQuery = CriteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyOwnEntitiy.class);

final Root<MyOwnEntitiy> myOwn = criteriaQuery.from(MyOwnEntitiy.class);

criteriaQuery.where(CriteriaBuilder.like(myOwn.get("idToText"), "%3%")))
```

I expect to see in hibernate sql the same or similar that I see in plain sql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly cast string to number with JPA2 Criteria API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394176/how-to-properly-cast-string-to-number-with-jpa2-criteria-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the `id` field as `Long`

```java
public class MyOwnTable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
```

and use `.as(String.class)` in criteria builder:

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
final Root<MyEntity> myOwn = criteriaQuery.from(MyEntity.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.like(myOwn.get("id").as(String.class), "%3%"));
TypedQuery<MyEntity> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<MyEntity> myEntitiesContainingThreeInId = typedQuery.getResultList()
```

Comment: Actually I used .as(String.class) but still got the same exception as my response, until I figured out that some other code produced that exception. This is the best way. Thanks for your effort.