# How to get json column as string in postgresql with jpa criteria builder?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, criteria, parseexception

I have a json column in table like:

```
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "json_data", columnDefinition = "json")
    private List<Persion> jsonData = Collections.emptyList();
```

```
    public class Persion implements Serializable {
        private String name;

        private int age;

        private String sex;
    }
```

And I want to query rows contains specific name in json, I have write this code:

```
    predicates.add(
            criteriaBuilder.like(
                criteriaBuilder.treat(root.get("jsonData"), String.class),
                "%" + name + "%"
        )
    )
```

But it throws exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

Can I just read json as string and then use where condition to query?
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Hi Harry, I read in the comments that you solved the problem. Can you help me, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
predicates.add(
        criteriaBuilder.like(
            criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", 
             String.class, root.get("jsonData"), 
             criteriaBuilder.literal("name")), "%" + name+ "%"
    )
)
```

I have found these links very helpful
[How do I use spring data jpa to query jsonb column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900457/how-do-i-use-spring-data-jpa-to-query-jsonb-column)
[Build predicates for a postgres jsonb column with criteria builder using JPA criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351772/build-predicates-for-a-postgres-jsonb-column-with-criteria-builder-using-jpa-cri)

Comment: thx first, The code you comment would work perfectly with json object, but mine is a json array. I alread change the table scheme. The question I asked was resolved. Thanks again.